# NetSuite I can't customize Transaction Forms even I have Administrator role

Tags: netsuite

I have Administrator role but I can't see edit/customize button in Transaction Form list Customization/Forms/Transaction Forms

When I click the form, it goes to that record.
ie, if I click any sales order form it goes to new Sales Order
No Edit/Customize button

Any idea please?

I have Administrator role and I tried to check permissions but I couldn't find any specific one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the custom transaction forms page, if you click on the name it will be a preview of the form i.e. to input a new record view. If you want to change the layout of the form, click the "Edit" link instead.

Another way is at any view transaction record page, click on "customise > Customised Form" link at the top right of the page.

Hope this help.